# Adding table column in currency format

Tags: jquery

I used this code to get the total of one column however its not computing correctly

Expected Output : 13,500.00
Currently Output: 13

i think the problem is in the format of number but i dont know how to deal with it.

```
 <table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <td>Col 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="amount">6,000.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="amount">1,500.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="amount">6,000.00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
            <div id="total"></div>
    <script>
    var theTotal = 0;
    $(".amount").each(function () {
        theTotal += parseInt($(this).html());
    });
    $("#total").html(theTotal);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the `,` from the string to parse string correctly.

```
theTotal += Number($(this).html().replace(/,/g,''));
// or remove all character except digit and dot
theTotal += Number($(this).html().replace(/[^\d.]/g,''));
```

**UPDATE :** Later convert into currency format by converting total into a string.

```
 $("#total").html(theTotal.toString().replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g,'$&,'))
 // or with 2 decimal point
 $("#total").html(theTotal.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+\.)/g,'$&,'))
```

Comment: your answer is correct but how will i output it in currency format?

Comment: is it possible to output like this  13,500.00

Comment: @ShermaineChaingan : check the second one with toFixed

Comment: Glad to help you :)